# phpmyadmin Triggers

Tags: trigger, phpmyadmin

welcome
I have three tables in a database and I want to link them

1. videos
2. channels
3. channels2

i have code

```
SET @channel=(Select channelnumber from channels where flag='0' and channelnumber not in (Select channelnumber from videos where dateend is NULL) limit 1);
```

I want to switch to "channels2" after "channels" is full

Comment: 'I want to switch to "channels2" after "channels" is full' -- Sounds dubious. Do you get an error message that tells you the tables was "full" from the DBMS? I never came across any database actually hitting any limit there, if there even is one. Two tables for the same entity usually is a design flaw and not necessary to cope with large numbers of records.

Comment: I put 30 channels in each table from 1 to 30 and the last is 31 to 60
The "Video" table must select a channel
If the first 30 channels are selected, it should automatically move to the second table
The idea is that each table is linked to a server

Comment: channel 1 https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/21225788?key=af5def7976f7271dea5d2c517d6e1113

Comment: channel 2 https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/21225755?key=2e623b75dfdd594aaae6ce3b8e95e117

Comment: So, like I already guessed, there's no technical reason for two tables. Then there shouldn't be two tables because logically it's just one entity. That is, all channels should be in *one* table. You can add a column to that table that assigns each channel to a "group" or a "server" or whatever you try to express with your two tables now.